# Is it possible to convert wired keyboard to wireless?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-networking

I have a happy hacking professional 2 keyboard, which cost about $300. I really love this keyboard, except that this is wired keyboard.

Is there any way to convert it to wireless keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:
http://www.cablesunlimited.com/products/Prod_Individual3.aspx?groupcode=I4098

It may even be possible to attach it directly to the bottom of the keyboard if you're good with a soldering iron.